# What Are the Possible Reasons Why an Error Pops out "Load Failed" in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2

I've Declared: ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
and name my crystal report viewer as: CRVreport

```
private void ViewLogBookEntryReport()
        {
            gvar.getReportPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportPath"]; <-- the path is correct i check like many times already.

            try
            {
                rptDoc.Load(gvar.getReportPath + "MineAgri\\" + "MinAgriLogbookEntryRpt.rpt");
                rptDoc.Refresh();

                rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@DtFrom", frmReports.GlobalForm.dtFrom.Text);
                rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@DtTo", frmReports.GlobalForm.dtto.Text);

                CRVreport.Refresh();
                CRVreport.ReportSource = rptDoc;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
        }
```

my XML data is like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="servername" value="MyServerName"/>
    <add key="DataSource" value="DBDB"/>
    <add key="UserID" value="sa"/>
    <add key="ReportPath" value="\\Folder01\shared files$\MINAGRI\Reports\"/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
```

I have a Program System which runs on a C# Programming Language under a SQL
Server and Crystal Report Viewer i created a new folder path which to
view a report it runs smoothly on my pc then comes a new PC which i
installed my system and shared the folder path via my local server but
then it still shows up "Load Failed" upon viewing the report when it
comes to my PC it works fine i  tried to make it similar the settings
of my PC to the new one but the error still pops out my question would
be what are the possible error that i haven't configure it yet in my
state of the problem right now? sorry about my english :( i'm working
as a OJT intern here please help any?

Comment: HAve you checked the security permissions? Post your code so we have something to look at.

Comment: i'm not that good actually in file sharing and networking is there something i need to check on that i've missed. but as far as i've done i check my file sharing folder and it's the same as my PC which can access the report but on the new one it still can't access it. always says "Load Failed"

Comment: So according to your code the path is \\Folder01\shared files$\MINAGRI\Reports\MineAgri\\MinAgriLogbookEntryRpt.rpt. The first flag that comes up for me is the double-backslash after MineAgri. That should be a single backslash.

Comment: What kind of an application is it? Can you add the reports to the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the report to the application and then reference it in one of the following ways:

For a web application use

`report.Load(Server.MapPath("MinAgriLogbookEntryRpt.rpt"));`

For a windows application use

`report.Load(Application.StartupPath + "MinAgriLogbookEntryRpt.rpt");`

Comment: so in this way sir if i just paste the debug folder of my source code in C# as a running exe for the application on the new pc without the whole code and place the report inside that folder same. it can be detected by using this method? if i use this method what would i put in my xml path? will i still use it or not anymore?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio by chance?

Comment: yes sir i tried doing it placing the report at the debug folder but it still says "Load Failed"

Comment: Open your program in Visual Studio and add the report through Visual Studio. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287885(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It's now ok sir.. i did some codes like this..

string Path = @"D:\\Reports\\MinAgriLogbookEntryRpt.rpt";
rptDoc.Load(Path, CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy);


thank you the help sir..